# App distribution is failed to AppStore with error : Invalid MinimumOSVersion

Tags: ios, app-store, archive

##### Error details:

> App Store Connect Operation Error

> Invalid MinimumOSVersion. The value for the Info.plist key MinimumOSVersion could not be parsed . With error code STATE_ERROR.VALIDATION_ERROR.90066 for id 9e066250-8ce2-40d6-a4b7-8a40356613f3

How to fix this problem?

[iOS deployment target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGXJc.png)

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JApP.png)

Comment: Please share a screenshot of your build settings for the parameter IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET.

Comment: Hello, I have already add the screenshot.

Comment: Hi @Satheesh, Could you take a look at it and give me some advice？

Answer (score 1):

Please check if the below value is properly set. [image: General Build Setting]

[image]

1. Target Setting General Pane.
2. Project Setting info pane.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The ".xcconfig" file in a sub project has content `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = iOS 11.0` written by someone in my team have be found. I think App Store should give more infomation for this issue to developer.....

Comment: Hi @you.X, I am also facing your problem. I have updated deployment target to 12.1 on all of subproject as well as main project but problem still happens. Do you have any other suggestions?